# readonly in invoice lines based on a value in line

Tags: odoo

I have a field 'uneditable' in 'account.invoice.line'.

I want to disable editing the line record if uneditable is true but creating enw line should be allowed.

my view code is as follows

```
<record model="ir.ui.view" id="invoice_supplier_form_ext">
        <field name="name">account.invoice.supplier.form</field>
        <field name="model">account.invoice</field>
        <field name='inherit_id' ref='account.invoice_supplier_form'/>
        <field name="type">form</field>
        <field name="arch" type="xml">
        <data>
            <field name="product_id" position="before">
                <field name="uneditable" invisible="1"/>
            </field>

            <field name="quantity" position="attributes">
                <attribute name="attrs">{'readonly': [('uneditable','=', True)]}</attribute>
            </field>
          </data>
        </field>
    </record>
```

Please suggest me what i am doing wrong. I am getting error with this code in view and does not make the line readonly.

Answer (score 2):

Actually your view is wrong. You have defined the fields 'quantity' and 'uneditable' in account.invoice.line and you are adding then in the invoice view. Please check the invoice_supplier_form view and add the fields correctly in the view.

```
<record model="ir.ui.view" id="invoice_line_form_ext">
    <field name="name">account.invoice.line.form</field>
    <field name="model">account.invoice.line</field>
    <field name='inherit_id' ref='account.view_invoice_line_form'/>
    <field name="type">form</field>
    <field name="arch" type="xml">
    <data>
        <field name="product_id" position="before">
            <field name="uneditable" invisible="1"/>
        </field>

        <field name="quantity" position="attributes">
            <attribute name="attrs">{'readonly': [('uneditable','=', True)]}</attribute>
        </field>
      </data>
    </field>
</record>
```